# Mongoose only returning id of the document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to `mongoose` and `mongodb`.Using this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular) to create my first application.

> When i use `mongoosemodel.find()` it returns only the Id of the
>   document.

*I have gone through the mongoose [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) still i'm confused about this.*

```
// define model =================
var User = mongoose.model('User',
 {
    firstName :String,
    lastName :String,

});
```

**Query**

```
User.find(function(err,users){
     if(err)
      response.send(err)

     console.log(users);             
     response.json(users);
});
```

- Is this a default behavior of mongoose ?
- Do i need to explicitly include my field name in the query.?
- How would i get all field ?

Please let me know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: @user3100115 still the same, is anything related to scheme

Comment: How to do that in shell

Comment: The monogdb also returns the same result , `id's and v`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That tutorial is missing the mongoose.Schema configuration so your "Create" isn't actually setting those two properties.

Try this when defining your model:

```
// define model =================
var User = mongoose.model('User',
 new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName :String,
    lastName :String,

}));
```

Comment: Still i have the same issue, I have added the complete code here http://pastebin.com/A3vc9RtC

Comment: Did you try adding another user *after* you added the correct schema setup?

Comment: in that case - you should log request.body on the post to make sure those properties are populated as expected. if they are not, you will have to look at your client code to figure out why they are not being deserialized on the server.